# Why do we use dummy coding and not binary coding in linear regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

I don't know if this doubt is very silly or not but is really bothering me.

I went through [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115049/why-do-we-need-to-dummy-code-categorical-variables/115052) answer. Here, in the most upvoted answer, the logic is binary coding does not get rid of the nonsensical quantitative relationship. The answer further suggests that dummy variables do not suffer from the same problem.

For example, if we have an unordered categorical variable with 4 levels, we cannot use (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) to show them as these are binary equivalent of 0,1,2,3 and numerical relationship is retained. But we can instead go with (0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0).

My doubt is why can't we consider it as binary equivalent of 0,1,2,4 and hence consider it to have the similar sort of numerical relationship? How does this solve the problem which binary coding was not able to?

Comment: Because you need the help the model as much as you can. A linear regression model will treat each column as independent, and if you look at `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`,`(1,0)`, and `(1,1)`. the model will see column `A` as $$\left(\matrix{0\\0\\1\\1}\right)$$ this is harder to differentiate as opposed to  $$\left(\matrix{0\\0\\0\\1}\right)$$  for example. Essentially you are embedding a mapping that the algorithm will have to decompose when you have a binary coding of the 4 outcomes.

Comment: This makes more sense, but if the only aim is to minimize correlation, then I am getting a gut feeling that there should be some other method which can out perform dummy coding. Or is it preferred because  of interpretability?

Comment: Linear models do better on linearly separable problems - if you use a neural net then you can decompose the rule (but we still tend to one hot encode things). However, for linear models I find the one hot encoding works best. Though I will have a think about it.